# Adjust delay in Watch display when turning wrist

Tags: sleep-wake, apple-watch, watchos

The Apple Watch spends most of its time sleeping with the display turned off. When you twist your wrist, it wakes and displays on screen.

Unfortunately, the Watch does not always appear for me.

Is there a way to make the Watch more sensitive to that wrist-twist motion? Or some setting to shorten the delay to wake-and-display?

I have a Series 1 Apple Watch running watchOS 4.3.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the generation of Apple Watch and watchOS version running on your Apple Watch.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Done.

Comment: There is apparently no setting in watchOS to shorted the said delay. However, since you are using Series 1 Watch, it is known be low on performance. That may explain the reason for delay.

Answer (score 2):

No. The only control you have is how long the screen stays lit once you activate. If you don’t like an exaggerated (or worse, making two wrist) movement(s), you would need totap a button or screen to wake the watch more promptly.